# Lotka-Volterra Matlab Model

Tags: matlab

I have to write a Lotka-Volterra model using matlab;

```
rabbit growth    X -> 2X              with rate k1*X
predation          X + Y -> 2Y        with rate k2*X*Y
fox death          Y -> 0                with rate k3*Y 

dX = @(k1,X,k2,Y) ((k1*X)-(k2*X*Y));
dY = @(k2,X,Y,k3) ((k2*X*Y)-(k3*Y));
funX = @ (X) dX(1,1,0.2,1);
funY = @ (Y) dY(0.2,1,1,0.5);
limits = [0 2000];

%%Plot graph
fplot (funX, limits,'R')
hold on
fplot(funY, limits, 'B')
ylabel ('Number of animals')
xlabel ('time (day)')
legend ('Rabbits', 'Foxes', 'Location', 'NorthEast')
```

I am simply getting a straight line, which is obviously not correct. Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you read the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka-Volterra), you see that LV is a differential equation. Where in your code are you solving it? What have you tried?

Comment: You are getting a straight line because in `funX = @ (X) dX(1,1,0.2,1)` the function does not depend on X, same for `funY`. Do the maths and come back with programming questions :-) Good luck with your homework.

Comment: You will find plenty of documentation online, including this: http://onlinemathcircle.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Lotka-Volterra-Equations.pdf